# jQuery - Delayed HTML function

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with doing two .html()'s in the same function cause the first one is getting overrun by the second.  Any thoughts?  This function is getting called when another action is taken, it is working fine, but when I put in the delay and the 2nd html() it doesn't work. Thanks.

```
function confirmNote() {
    $('#noteConfirm').html('Note Sent').delay(1000).html('Leave a Note');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.delay()` only works with functions that go through the animation queue which does not include `.html()`.  You can use a `setTimeout()` to do what you want.

```
function confirmNote() {
    $('#noteConfirm').html('Note Sent');
    setTimeout(function() {$('#noteConfirm').html('Leave a Note')}, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function confirmNote() {
    $('#noteConfirm').html('Note Sent')
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#noteConfirm').html('Leave a Note');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Should do the trick. `delay` only delays animation so is not appropriate in this case.